# how to export/dump mysql without index

Tags: mysql, indexing, import, export

I exported sql from server and importing into my local.

But it takes too much time to import the sql, I think it's related with index.

Can I export the sql without index?

And after import the sql, apply indexes to tables. Is this possible?

Comment: How did you do the export?  If via mysqldump, look at the dump file; you will see that it is doing the indexes optimally.  What is the goal of the export/import (backup, transport, other?)  For further discussion, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the slow tables.

Comment: I can't show the file, since its size larger than 1 GB.
I dumped the sql via mysqldump.
When I import this sql into server, it takes too much time.

Answer (score 4):

`--disable-keys` only works for MyISAM tables. I have done a lot of searching and not found any similar way to do this for InnoDB.

What I do is to use [hexedit](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit), press `Tab`, type `/` and the name of the table, hit enter, when it finds the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the large table causing issues, I navigate to the `PRIMARY KEY`/`UNIQUE KEY`/`KEY` second and remove all indexes by replacing them with spaces. After save file, load the dump, and immediately after recreate the same indexes manually. For my data (150 GB and 1.5 billion rows) it takes 5 hours instead of 15.

Answer (score 1):

From the `mysqldump` doc:

> --disable-keys, -K
>
> For each table, surround the INSERT statements with /*!40000 ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS */; and /*!40000 ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS */; statements. This makes loading the dump file faster because the indexes are created after all rows are inserted. This option is effective only for nonunique indexes of MyISAM tables. It has no effect for other tables.